# Style header CSS

Tags: css

I want to create header for my website widgets.
The header is like below image : 
[image]

I wrote this code now :

```
.Widget-Header
{

    background-color: #f7901e;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Sansation;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;

}
```

Now I don't know how to style header icon and title.

SHould I consider separate tag for header text and Icon ? 

How do I do for header Icons ? Would you please give an example ?

### Update

I want to use this header class for some header containers with diffrent Icons.
So How do I do now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it all with CSS and a background image. That way, the markup is clean (presentation and structure is separated) users who disable CSS will not need to download the image and still retain a functional anchor.

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UDBRG/2/) - using a single style for the majority of the properties and defining one extra rule for each icon as a `background-image` property.

[**Updated Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/UDBRG/7/) since the elements should be headings, so have made them `<h2>` and moved the anchor to the right side, matching the original question.

#### HTML

```
<h2 class="first">Stop Clock<a href="#">+</a></h2>
<h2 class="second">Something else<a href="#">+</a></h2>
```

#### CSS

```
h2 {
    background: #f7901e no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Sansation;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    width:400px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:50px;
    line-height:2;
    position:relative;
}

.first {
    background-image:url(http://lorempixum.com/40/40/city/1)
}

.second {
    background-image:url(http://lorempixum.com/40/40/city/2)
}

h2 a {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:15px;
    background:url(http://lorempixum.com/10/10) no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-indent:1000px;
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:1;
}
```

Comment: Seems good. thank you.
but I think this code is not customizable much.
I mean about changing icon for per header .
am I right ? :]

Comment: Because I want to use this class header for more that one Div with different Icons.

Comment: Please see my Update if possible.

Comment: Updated the demo based on your additional requirements

Comment: Your code works fine and its really good.
But please review my heading picture again if possible.
there is plus Icon right side of picture and I use it in all my headers .
Would you please suggest me how can I add it to my css for cleaner markup ?

Comment: Updated again which should better match the sample in the question. Let me know if you need any part of it explaining in more detail or have any issues. Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

first create a master div to hold both divs

```
#holder {
 width: 800px;
 overflow: hidden; /* so the floats stay in the div */
 background: orange;
}
```

then create styling for the divs inside the master holder

```
#left {
 float: left; /* the div will float left with link being the width of the object in it*/
}

#right {
 float: right; /* will float right, with same property */
}
```

finally your html would look like this

```
<div id="holder">
 <div id="left">
  this text is floated to left
 </div>

 <div id="right">
  this text is floated to right
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks 
For Header Icon :
How do I do for header Icon ?
should I use Img tag ? Or its better to using Style ?

Comment: if you can do it using text only use styling, otherwise use image, but eventually you would need to create the stopwatch, then the text, thats the same concept, float inside the small div (#left)

Answer (score 1):

You should use separate tags for the header items if you want to be able to refer to or manipulate them later; for example, to play with spacing. HTML should be used for semantics and CSS should be used for display.

Based on the information you've given, no additional tags should be required for your header to look like your image. This is because everything inside `Widget-Header` will inherit the style properties of `Widget-Header`.

Comment: Thanks 
For Header Icon :
How do I do for header Icon ?
should I use Img tag ? Or its better to using Style ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If it's an image, you're pretty much stuck with the `<img ...` tag. I suppose you could make it a background, but it doesn't seem like you're actually using it as a background.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/as8RQ/3/

---

I would recommend breaking it up into elements, a wrapper for everything, a container for the left image, and a container for the right image. Check out the fiddle...

### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/as8RQ/1/

### HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="plus"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#header {
    background-color: #f7901e;
    height: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    background: url("/path/to/your/image") no-repeat;
    height: 36px; /* same height as #header height */
    width: 148px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 16px;
}
#plus {
    background: url("/path/to/your/image") no-repeat;
    height: 36px; /* same height as #header height */
    width: 41px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 16px;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: gotcha... give me a couple of minutes to refactor this